# Как перезаписать json файл и сохранить изменения внутри zip архива c помощью PHP?

Tags: php, json, zip

этот код открывает zip архив, декодирует json, изменяет нужное значение, но сохраняет измененный json в корень диска, а не перезаписывает файл внутри архива.

Есть идеи, какой код должен быть, чтобы измененный json сохранялся и перезаписывался внутри архива?

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('2.zip');

$contents = '';
$fp = $zip->getStream('456.json');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 2);
}

fclose($fp);

$zip->close();

$decode_json_nick = json_decode($contents, true);


$decode_json_nick['status']="avalible";    // изменил значение здесь
$contents1 = json_encode($decode_json_nick);
file_put_contents('456.json', $contents1);  // тут нужно сохранить именно внутри архива
```

Comment: создать новый архив? https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.zip.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось все намного проще и самое главное скрипт работает!
Так-что берите рабочий скрипт, может кому пригодится.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('2.zip');                // открываю архив с именем 2.zip

$contents = '';
$fp = $zip->getStream('456.json');  //  получаю доступ к файлу 456.json, который внутри архива 2.zip
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $contents .= fread($fp, 2);
}

fclose($fp);

$decode_json_nick = json_decode($contents, true);


$decode_json_nick['status']="avalible";    // изменил значение здесь
$contents1 = json_encode($decode_json_nick);
file_put_contents('456.json', $contents1);  // сохраняет в корень директории

$zip->addFile('456.json'); // заносим файл в архив
$zip->close();

unlink('456.json'); // удаляем файл копии в корне директории
```